# Divide by the highest power or divide by the denominator highest power?

Tags: calculus

When resolving limits that $x\to \pm ∞$ the teacher taught us to divide by the highest power. But I've seen some that divide by the highest power **in the denominator**

First thing it comes to my mind is that it can be archived either way.

if I divide by the highest power in the entire fraction

$$\Large\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{4x^2+x^6}{1-5x^3}\right)\:$$

$$=\Large\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:\:}=\left(\frac{\frac{4x^2}{x^6}+\frac{x^6}{x^6}}{\frac{1}{x^6}-\frac{5x^3}{x^6}}\right)$$

$$=\Large\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:\:}=\left(\frac{\frac{4}{x^4}+1}{\frac{1}{x^6}-\frac{5}{x^3}}\right)=\:\frac{0+1}{0-0}\:=\:\frac{1}{0}\:=\:∞?$$

But... continuing with the same example above, If I divide by the highest power **in the denominator**:

$$\Large\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{4x^2+x^6}{1-5x^3}\right)\:$$

$$\Large=\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:\:}\left(\frac{\frac{4x^2}{x^3}+\frac{x^6}{x^3}}{\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{5x^3}{x^3}}\right)\:$$

$$\Large=\lim \:\:_{x\to \:\:\infty \:\:\:}\left(\frac{\frac{4}{x}+x^3}{\frac{1}{x^3}-5}\right)\:=\frac{∞}{-5}\:=\:-∞$$

My questions are:

1. Can it be archived both ways? If so what I'm doing wrong in the first example?
2. If the method you use depends on something, on what?

Comment: "$\,\frac{1}{0}\:=\:\infty\,$" $\;$ That's wrong in general, and this is one case which makes it obvious that it's wrong.

Comment: @dxiv So dividing by the highest power give me undefine? meaning I should then proceed to try with the highest power **in the denominator**? can you expand please? thank you for responding

Comment: You generally don't divide by the highest power in the denominator. It is standard to divide by the highest power in the function. Similar post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832699/dividing-each-term-by-the-highest-degree-in-the-denominator-of-a-limit-that-goes

Comment: Have you learned anything aout Taylor Series yet?

Comment: @centenond Try to focus on the purpose rather than the mechanics of it. The purpose is to bring the denominator to a form with a finite non-zero limit, then the behavior is dictated by the numerator alone. Whether that means multiplying by a conjugate or dividing by a power depends on the particular problem, but the end purpose is always the same. In your case here, you achieve that purpose by dividing by the highest power in the denominator. It does not mean that you are not allowed to divide by the highest power in the numerator, or by any power for that matter, it's just that it won't help.

Comment: Thank you! "The purpose is to bring the denominator to a form with a finite non-zero limit" that helps a lot!  So the way I would know if that won't work is that if by dividing the denominator gives me 0 or +-∞?

Answer (score 2):

So, at one stage, you have

$$L = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1 + 4/x^4}{1/x^6 - 5/x^3}$$

Firstly, $1/0$ does not mean anything. It is not $\infty,-\infty,$ or anything; it is simply undefined. Hence, taking the limit as you did and getting $1/0$ as an answer (regardless of the fact you conclude $L = \infty$ thereafter) is a hint you are probably doing something wrong, or at least overlooking a nuance of the situation.

Consider the fact that $x^3 < x^6$ for $x$ large (and in particular as $x \to \infty$). Then $1/x^6 < 1/x^3 < 5/x^3$, right? And then therefore,

$$\frac{1}{x^6} - \frac{5}{x^3} < 0$$

Think of the ramifications of this as you take the limit: the numerator is growing closer and closer to $1$, but the denominator is growing closer and closer to zero **from the left (negative) side of $0$**. Whatever that denominator may be can be incredibly small, but it will be negative. Hence,

$$L = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac 1 x = -\infty$$

would be the more correct and formal claim. (You intuited that the limit was $1/x$, but did not consider the direction and went with a common "default" of $x \to 0^+$ giving $+\infty$.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write, my teacher said that 1/0 = ∞  only when talking about infinite limits, but that you can't explicitly write 1/0 = ∞, I wrote it to share my thought process. He said that what would determine the sign of the infinity is the sign of the highest power. But that approach failed so. I guess what he didn't tell me is that if the highest power is in the numerator the sign of the denominator's highest powers matters too.

Answer (score 2):

> "...the purpose is to bring the denominator to a form with a finite non-zero limit..." -dxiv

I think this is the key insight toward making these problems easier; and I'll take it a step further saying that you want to do it for the numerator as well!

---

So what is the problem at hand?
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty\:}\left(\frac{4x^2+x^6}{1-5x^3}\right)=\ ?
$$
So, we have a polynomial of order $x^6$ in the numerator, and a polynomial of order $x^3$ in the denominator... so what wins out in the limit?

Following dxiv's advice about the denominator, we can rearrange that a bit by dividing out powers of $x$ until all that remains should be finite when we take the limit... in other words:
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty \:} \left(1-5x^3\right) = \lim _{x\to \infty \:} x^3 \left(-5 + \frac{1}{x^3} \right)
$$
The $x^3$ outside will still need to be contended with later, but we do at least know that the part left inside the parentheses will stay finite as we approach that infinite limit.

If we play the same games with the numerator:
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty \:} \left(4x^2+x^6\right) = \lim _{x\to \infty \:} x^6 \left(1 + \frac{4}{x^4} \right)
$$
then we once again have an exterior infinity to deal with, but the portion inside will stay finite as we approach the infinite limit.

And then, when we finally bring it all together:
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty\:}\left(\frac{4x^2+x^6}{1-5x^3}\right)=
\lim _{x\to \infty\:}\left(\frac{x^6 (1+\frac{4}{x^4})}{x^3 (-5+\frac{1}{x^3})} \right) =\:?
$$
then we see that we have two finite quantities in parentheses, and outside that we have some $x$ powers that will partially cancel out.
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty\:}\left(\frac{4x^2+x^6}{1-5x^3}\right)=
\lim _{x\to \infty\:}\left(x^3 \frac{(1+\frac{4}{x^4})}{(-5+\frac{1}{x^3})} \right) \approx \lim _{x\to \infty\:} \frac{x^3}{-5}
$$

Answer (score 1):

These are both heuristic suggestions.  They work enough of the time to try them, and there is no reason except lack of success to stop trying one of them.

If you distinguish between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ note that you need to consider the signs.  Are your limits $x \to +\infty$?  Or can $x$ get large in either direction.  In your first example the denominator has the sign of $x$ so the limit as $x \to -\infty$ is $-\infty$.  In your second example the numerator has the sign of $x$ while the denominator is negative, so the limit as $x \to -\infty$ is $+\infty$.  You need to be consistent.